# Не работает objects.filter django

Tags: python, django

почему не выполняется filter?
в браузере ссылка `http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/?category=simple`
фильтр не делает выборку по `list_orders = Orders.objects.filter(category__category=category_filter)`, отдает все записи, которые есть в базе, а не те, где только встречается эта категория

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Что ремонтируем')  
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категория', related_name='get_category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Наименования категории')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Категория')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views**

```
class OrdersHomeView(ListView):
    model = Orders
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'orders/orders_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'orders'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        category_filter = self.request.GET.get('category')
        list_orders = Orders.objects.filter(category__category=category_filter) 
        paginator = Paginator(list_orders, self.paginate_by)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

> Не работает objects.filter django

Работает. Проверено.

У вас метод возвращает контекст.

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # вот это
        category_filter = self.request.GET.get('category')
        list_orders = Orders.objects.filter(category__category=category_filter) 
        paginator = Paginator(list_orders, self.paginate_by)
        return context  # вот туть
```

Возможно вам стоить поменять на `return paginator`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы в get_context_data возвращаете context т.е `context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)` и так как вы возвращаете context,то и выводится будет совсем другое.